# Url rewriting form .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a site with 2 languages en and de with the de files in the html directory and the en file in html/en . I would like to make the link that is currently website.com/en to be the website/com and the website.com to be the webisite.com/de from the .htaccess file.

From the website i have 2 button: 1 for English.html and 1 for Deutsch.html and in .htaccess i have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /switch_lang.php?pmode=select_lang&lang=$1  [L]
```

which takes the links from above and make a request to switch_lang.php. But my url stays the same for both languages. I would like for the de language to be `http://alpinepeaks.ch/de` instead of  `http://alpinepeaks.ch/`

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't seem to make much sense. What's website/com? You should try to be clearer about what should redirect where...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like a simple swap to me...the logical thing seems to be

if

- "de" files are in the root directory (html) --> url: domain.com
- and "en" files are in the "en" directory --> url: domain.com/en

then

- put the "en" files in the root directory (html) --> url: domain.com
- and the "de" files in the "de" directory --> url: domain.com/de

but then again I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. The website/com kind threw me

Comment: From the page i have 2 buttons. One for english and one for german. When i make the request in the .htaccess i have the rule : `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /switch_lang.php?pmode=select_lang&lang=$1 [L]` witch take the English.html or Deutch.html and send it to switch_lang.php where the request are made ... also the link does not change durring this process.